# Python ImportError. How can I import modules among packages?

Tags: python, error-handling, module, importerror, relative-path

I was working on a project with this type of folder tree:

```
-main.py

  -Message_handlers
     -__init__.py
     -On_message.py
     -Other_modules.py
  
  -Exceptions_handler
     -__init__.py
     -Run_as_mainException.py
```

**Message_handlers** and **Exceptions_handler** are two packages, now my problem is that from inside the module **On_message.py** I can't import the class Run_as_mainException (inside of the module **Run_as_mainException.py**) using this code

```
# This is On_message.py
from ..Exceptions_handler.Run_as_mainException import Run_as_main_Exception
```

This line gives the error: `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`

p.s. Every file has a class inside with the same name of the file, example:

```
# This is Run_as_mainExample.py
class Run_as_mainExample:
    def __init__(self):
        # rest of the code
```

Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assume that you're running everything from the level where main.py is located. This means, imagine that you execute `python main.py`, and you want to import `Run_as_main_Exception` from `main.py`, what should you do?

```
from Exceptions_handler.Run_as_mainException import Run_as_main_Exception
```

Try using that line in your On_message.py file, and you shouldn't have any problem when running your script from that exact location (remember, the same level where main.py is located)

Comment: I've already tried it but it doesn't work for me. It gives me this error:  **from Exceptions_handler.Run_as_mainException import Run_as_mainException** and **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Exceptions_handler'**